# Very strange wordpress behaviour with shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I'm witnessing a very strange phenomenon on one page (http://can.org.uk/training/training-diary) on our wp site. The page exhibiting the strange behaviour is processed by single.php and the post has a shortcode in it. The shortcode is:

[tcal tag=course]

This shortcode should generate a table containing all the posts tagged with 'course' within the current category. Now I know the code works as it was working this morning and, if I put an echo at the bottom of the shortcode function then I can see that the relevant table hase been built and is begin returned by the function.

Problem is, the page simply shows as blank ... nothing at all shows up.

Also, even stranger still, after just checking again, now the entire site shows as blank ... e.g. if I go to the home page http://can.org.uk then I see nothing at all - at least on my home laptop it shows blank, on my work pc it seems to work just fine (except for the page mentioned earlier).

I can log into the dashboard and all looks just fine. 
I don't have any plugins installed.

Anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked into your php error log file or turned on php errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might it be "headers already sent"? Try turning on `WP DEBUG` on config file and set error reporting to all, I'm pretty sure it will be header issue.

Check, if on plain .php file you don't have space between `...?> <?php...` somewhere.

Comment: turning on the debugging - which I didn't know about :( - showed up a few errors, one of them being headers already sent!

Comment: Try to do your best fixing them one by one, headers allready sent would be the one to start with.

Comment: Also, Update your original post and paste in the errors, might give more clues. If you don't want to do that, line numbers at the end of errors will help with the fixing and mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should always just return the output of your shortcode , not echo it. if you just output it , Wordpress will take care of the rendering for you.

here is a simple one , for instance :

```
function test_function($attributes){
    return "<p><b>SHORTCODE TEST:</b>
  <br/>these are the attributes ".
    implode($attributes," ")."</p>";
}
```